# mocha chaijs : $ is not defined

Tags: mocha.js, chai

I'm trying to setting up automated test.
I'm using zombiejs for the browser, mochaJs for the test framework and chaiJs for assertion. I want to use `chai-jq` for jquery assertion:

```
var expect  = require('chai').expect
var chai    = require("chai");
var chaiJq  = require('chai-jq');
Browser     = require('zombie'),
browser     = new Browser();

chai.use(chaiJq); 
describe('Test', function(){

before(function(done) {
browser.visit('http://localhost/login.php', done);
});

  describe('Connexion au site', function() {

before(function(done) {
  browser
    .fill('login',    'foo')
    .fill('password', 'bar')
    .pressButton('Connexion', done);
});

it('should be successful (code 200)', function() {
  browser.assert.success(200);
});
});

    describe('', function() {

browser.visit('http://localhost/activites/nationales/accueil.php');

    it('contain text', function() {
      var $elem = $("<div id=\"hi\" foo=\"bar time\" />");

        expect($elem)
          // Assertion object is `$elem`
          .to.have.$attr("id", "hi").and
          // Assertion object is still `$elem`
          .to.contain.$attr("foo", "bar");
    });
});
```

When I run the test i've got the error `ReferenceError: $ is not defined`

Comment: This is the line you have to change: `var $elem = $("<div id=\"hi\" foo=\"bar time\" />");`. I suspect you want to use jQuery there. Perhaps you may look into some webdriver/zombie command for the same function.

Comment: yes I want to use jquery, this is why I imported `chai-jq` for chai jquery as described on their doc http://chaijs.com/plugins/chai-jq/

Comment: Yes, I see. The problem is that you are using it in the wrong context. Your test context is outside of the page and `browser` is your only way to it. You need to ask the `browser` to get that element by `id` for you.